# Linq: differences between C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

While converting some of my code from VB to C# I'm having a hard time with this query:

```
Dim r = From v In VTab
    Group v By v.ID Into g = Group
    Select
      ID,
      Value = g.Where(Function(x) [...]).Sum(Function(x) x.Value),
      Ann = (g.Where(Function(X) [...]).Count > 0)
    From f In FTab.Where(Function(x) Value >= x.Min And Value <= x.Max).DefaultIfEmpty
    Select New Result With {
    .ID = ID,
    .Value = Value,
    .Ann = Ann,
    .Data = f.Data
    }
```

This basically groups values from VTab, obtaining one row per ID with a sum and a boolean, then joins this partial result with FTab and gives the final result.

This is the closest result I could get:

```
var r = from v in VTab
    group v by v.ID into g
    select g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value) into Value
    from f in FTab.Where(x => Value >= x.Min && Value <= x.Max)
    select new Result
    {
        Value = Value
    };
```

I don't know how to specify multiple fields in the first select.

This is what I tried:

```
select g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value) into Value
select g.Where(x => [...]).Count() > 0 into Ann // g doesn't exist in the current context

// Syntax error
select g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value) into Value, g.Where(x => [...]).Count() > 0 into Ann

// Syntax error
select g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value) into Value,
select g.Where(x => [...]).Count() > 0 into Ann

// ; expected at the end of the line and I can't continue with the query
select new { Value = g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value), Ann = g.Where(x => [...]).Count() > 0}
```

Comment: Have you tried any online converter eg. https://converter.telerik.com/ - they are pretty good IMHO

Comment: Unfortunately every converter I tried (including telerik) throws an exception with this query ;)

Comment: You are probably looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var r = VTab
.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
.Select(x => new { 
    ID = x.Key, 
    Value = x.Where(y => true).Sum(y => 1),
    Ann = x.Where(y => true).Count() > 0
})
.Select(x => new Result() {
    ID = x.ID,
    Value = x.Value,
    Ann = x.Ann,
    Data = FTab.Where(y => x.Value >= y.Min && x.Value <= y.Max).FirstOrDefault()?.Data
});
```

Comment: How about an explanation to go with it?

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I would like to know how to write this query using query syntax instead of method syntax. In query syntax, if I use an anonymous type for the first select, I don't know how to refernece it in the second one.

Comment: @Disti - sorry, but I am bad at query syntax

Answer (score 1):

After some more trial and error, I've been able to translate my query:

```
var r = from v in VTab
    group v by v.ID into g
    select new 
    { 
        ID = g.Key,
        Value = g.Where(x => [...]).Sum(x => x.Value), 
        Ann = g.Where(x => [...]).Count() > 0}
    } into t
    from f in FTab.Where(x => t.Value >= x.Min && t.Value <= x.Max).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Result
    {
        ID = t.ID,
        Value = t.Value,
        Ann = t.Ann,
        Data = f?.Data
    };
```

The key here is to use "**into t**" to identify the object created in the first select, and then refer to it in the second one.